# Use google ML Kit with react native

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-mlkit

I want to remove backgrounds from images in my react native app. I am already using Firebase in my app, so I tried to find something in Firebase Machine Learning that can do that, but unfortunately not. It seems that the function was moved to a separate SDK, [ML Kit](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/selfie-segmentation). Is there any way to use this selfie-segmentation feature with react-native? Or is there something similar in firebase?

Comment: ML Kit does not support react native.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ML Kit wrapper for RN called https://github.com/a7medev/react-native-ml-kit

In your case, unfortunately, it is not implemented yet in this library but you can add it following this PR https://github.com/a7medev/react-native-ml-kit/pull/20/files